# Creating image slider with images and caption

Tags: html, css, image, text, slider

[image][image]I am attempting to create a horizontal image slider using html and css.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image-container">
        <center>
              <div class="image">
                <div class="image-box">1</div>
                <div class="text-box">
                    Hello
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="image">2</div>
              <div class="image">3</div>
              <div class="image">4</div>
            </div>
        </center>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: The 1,2,3,4 will be later replaced by actual image. I want image to fit in inage-box div and under it in text-box div- i want a title and its title name displayed.

This is my css code:

```
.image-container {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}


.image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 100px; 
  border: 5px red solid;
}

.image-box{
    height:150px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
}

.text-box{
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 5px red solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

When i remove the text inside text box, i get the boxes aligned correctly(see image-1.png in attachment) and it is scroll-able too but when i am trying to add the text like Hello inside it to check, the text is not aligned and goes outside(see attachment image-2.png). I want the text to fit inside this text-box only and not go outside. I checked online and found properties like `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` but it is not helping me.
Can someone help me rectify this so text(like a title and its name) should be within this text-box itseld?

Comment: Solution for this: I searched and added a line-height for <p> after which text appears inside the text-box

Answer (score 0):

Using **display:flex** should solve your problem.

```
.image-container {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 5px red solid;
}
```

Maybe you have a look at bootstrap framework or foundation framework how they solved it - or even use it for your Website.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't solve my problem. It changed my image slider into vertical with no text